# Javascript replace with reference to matched group on all matches

Tags: javascript, regex

my sample text is :

```
'<div class="emoji-icons emoji-smile" e-type="smile" style="display:inline-block;" contenteditable="false"></div> is <div class="emoji-icons emoji-grinning" e-type="grinning" style="display:inline-block;" contenteditable="false"></div> very time.'
```

replace command is :

```
text.replace(/<div class="emoji-icons (?:.*)" e-type="([a-z]*)"[^>]+><\/div>/ig, '$1')
```

i want replace all div tag with e-type attribute value.
result must be "smile is grinning vary time."

but this regex not work on all matched and work on last matches.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: *"Any ideas or suggestions?"* Yes. [**Don't use regular expressions to manipulate HTML.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `(?:.*)"` with `(?:.*?)"` , also there is no need for `()` so just use `.*?"`

```js
var text = '<div class="emoji-icons emoji-smile" e-type="smile" style="display:inline-block;" contenteditable="false"></div> is <div class="emoji-icons emoji-grinning" e-type="grinning" style="display:inline-block;" contenteditable="false"></div> very time.';

text = text.replace(/<div class="emoji-icons.*?" e-type="([a-z]*)"[^>]+><\/div>/ig, '$1')

document.write(text);
```

> **.*?** :  Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible

Comment: @mrlayeghi : glad to help